# Sails: Use different projects in a single server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, sails.js

Can we make `subapps` in `sails` like we use in `express`. Or I have to use some custom solution.
I need to run 6 `sails` processes in one server.

I have 6 different projects which needs to be run under single node service.